# Error to compile a tex file

Tags: errors, compilation-error

7 years ago I wrote a math thesis in LaTeX on Windows7 (x64), and now I had to compile again my `.tex` file, but I have a problem.

On my personal computer (Windows 10 x64) everything is OK, but on my computer from the office (also Windows 10 x64) is not working and I have the following errors:

```
LaTeX Error: File `algorithmic.sty' not found.
l.9 \usepackage
               {algorithm}

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Then install  algorithmic.sty with the tools of your (unknown) tex system.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution would be to find the two files `algorithmic.sty` and `algorithm.sty` on your home computer and copy those two files to the folder that contains your `.tex` file on your office computer. But a better solution is to install the package as suggested, using the MikTex package manager, or the TeX Live package manager `tlmgr`, or manually directly from CTAN.

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Answer (score 1):

I think the package is not installed in your system

To install this package use this command for Texlive user in your terminal window make sure that you have an internet connectivity

`tlmgr install algorithms`

[image]

For MikTeX users can prefer this link [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)